# Is there a general name for the types of books which are to be treated with respect?

Tags: words, names, jewish-books

Is there a general name for the types of books which are to be treated with respect?  For example: a siddur, a Tanach, a copy of the Hagaddah, Megilat Esther, or Talmud. Might we call these *holy books*, sifrei kodesh, or is that misleading?

Sample usage: When her grandfather passed away, she cleaned out his library, deciding to keep only the ***_*_**.

Comment: I'm thinking sheimos, as in sheimos sheainam nimchakim

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, *sifrei kodesh* (ספרי קודש) is the common term.

Answer (score 3):

Colloquialy we refer to them as **Sefarim** (**Sefer** in singular), as opposed to books which are not treated with respect.

She kept the *Sefarim* and threw out the *books*.

This does not work when talking Hebrew.

Comment: +1 for "this does not work when talking Hebrew. Many Anglos speak as if it does